# Creating new user with firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to Firebase and have been trying to implement a "Sign Up" page for my app. Currently, I am only using the email feature, just to test things out. I am able to create the new user and store it in the "Login & Auth" tab in the dashboard, but for what ever reason I cannot retrieve the UID. The only way is if I close out of my app and reload it, then it can access the UID. Any suggestions on why this is?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a code snippet and any Firebase data structure you currently have. Text only please, no pictures. Then refine your question so we know what you are asking; are you getting an error in code? What's the result? Also, you may want to review the user authentication page on the Firebase website as it walks you through authentication [User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html)

Comment: Well, I figured out a solution. For whatever reason I could not grab the user UID from the my sign up page. I just segued into another view controller and now I can grab the UID.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.1 FireBase User Create/Login Steps:-**

**STEP 1:- Register new  firebase authentication Pod in to your Podfile :**

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

**STEP 2:- Open terminal and install pod  with your related project directory path:**

```
pod install
```

**STEP 3:- import firebase authentication library in your UIViewController where ever you want:**

```
import FirebaseAuth
```

**STEP 4:- On your Registration UIButton Action write this snippet :**

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (txtEmail.text ?? ""), password: (txtPass.text ?? "")) { (result, error) in
            if let _eror = error {
                //something bad happning
                print(_eror.localizedDescription )
            }else{
                //user registered successfully
                print(result)
            }
         }
```

**STEP 5:- If you want to Sign In after Registration use this snippet on your Sign in UIButton:**

```
  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: (txtEmail.text ?? ""), password: (txtPass.text ?? "")) { (result, error) in
            if let _eror = error{
                print(_eror.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                if let _res = result{
                    print(_res)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Happy Codding ;)!!!!**

Answer (score 2):

Example of how to create users:

```
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
                UserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result.uid, forKey: "uid")

                print("Account created :)")

                let userDict = ["Name": name!, "Major": major!, "Email": email!]

                let uid = result!.uid

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        else{
                print(error)
        }
    })
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Creating user in Firebase is very easy, just add firebase to your project using cocoa pods and then create a signup screen. You need email and password. Now first import Firebase

```
import Firebase
```

Then inside on viewDidLoad() method configure firebase

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

Now get email and password from textfields and use the following code for registration.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
   if error == nil {
       //registration successful
   }else{
       //registration failure
   }
})
```

Thats it.

Source: **[Firebase Swift Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/firebase-ios-tutorial-user-registration/)**

Answer (score 1):

Before you try any code, make sure your password is at least 6 characters long. Print the error if is possible, I would print the error on each function. sign up and sign in just to keep track of what you are doing.

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.usernameTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {(user, error) in
    if user != nil {
        print("User Has SignUp")
    }
    if error != nil {
        print(":(",error)
    }
}
   Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.usernameTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {(user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            print("User Has Sign In")
        }
        if error != nil {
            print(":(",error)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Firebase Authentication

It is a Backend Service to authorise using Email/Password or Phone Number/Password. It also supports OAuth2.0 and OpenID Authentication like Google SignIn, Facebook Authentication, Twiiter Authentication and Github Authentication.

*AuthenticationWorker* is singleton class for Firebase Authentication

*Note* : In Firebase Console, you've to *enable* Sign-In Method for *Email/Password* provider.

#### SigIn with Existing User

In AuthenticationWorker, there is a method called *login(handler:)* which will return user:FIRUser and error:Error in completion closure.

```swift
let user = UserModel(email: "ab.abhishek.ravi@gmail.com", password: "myPassword")

AuthenticationWorker.shared.login(user: user, handler: { (user, error) in

guard error == nil else {

  // Error Occurred While Authentication
  print(error.localizedDescription)

  return
}

//Successfully Authenticated
print(user)

})
```

#### SignUp New User

In AuthenticationWorker, we have a method called *register(user: handler:)*. In Response, It will return UserModel FIRUser type object along with the Error Optional

```swift
AuthenticationWorker.shared.register(user: user, handler: { (user, error) in

guard error == nil else {

  //onError Occurred While Registering
  print(error.localizedDescription)
  return
}

//onSuccessfull Registration
print(user)

})
```

#### Get Active User

In Authentication Worker, we have a method called *isLoggedIn()->User?*. As you can, this method will either return User instance or nil.

```swift
if let user = AuthenticationWorker.shared.isLoggedIn() {
            print(user)
}
```

#### Update password

In Authentication Worker, we've a method called *updatePassword(newPassword: handler:)* to change the loggedin account password.

```swift
AuthenticationWorker.shared.updatePassword(newPassword: "NewPassword") { (hasChanged, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //onSuccess
            print(hasChanged)
}
```

#### Update Email Address

In Authentication Worker, there is a method called *updateEmailAddress(newEmail: hanlder:)* which will update the email address of the logged-in account.

```swift
AuthenticationWorker.shared.updateEmailAddress(newEmail: "newEmailAddress@gmail.com") { (user, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //Successfully changed Email Address of LoggedIn Account
            print(user)
}
```

#### Send Verification Mail

If you want to integrate Verification-Process while registering you can call *sendVerificationMail(handler:)* method to send Verification Mail to logged account.

And, Whenever you logged-in any account, you'll get a bool property isEmailVerified in *User* which will return whether you account is verified or not.

```swift
AuthenticationWorker.shared.sendVerificationMail { (hasSent, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //onSuccessfully Sent Verification Mail
            print(hasSent)
}
```

#### Remove Account

In Authentication Worker, you have a provision to delete User from the Firebase Authentication Catalog.

```swift
AuthenticationWorker.shared.deleteUser { (hasDeleted, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //onSuccessfull Deletion of User
            print(hasDeleted)
}
```

**AuthenticationWorker.swift**

```
//
//  AuthenticationWorker.swift
//  FirebaseAuth
//
//  Created by Brahma on 04/05/23.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

struct UserModel {
    
    var email:String
    var password: String
    
    init(email:String, password: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    }
}

class AuthenticationWorker {
    
    typealias completionHandler = (User?, Error?)->()
    typealias onCompletion = (Bool, Error?)->()
    
    static let shared = AuthenticationWorker()
    
    let authenticationObject = Auth.auth()
    
    /// Login ith User Model where You have Email and Password
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - user: UserModel Object
    ///   - handler: Completion Handler with User Optional Object  and Error Optional
    func login(user: UserModel, handler: @escaping completionHandler) {
        
        authenticationObject.signIn(withEmail: user.email, password: user.password) { (user, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                //onError
                if let error = error {
                    handler(nil, error)
                }
                return
            }
            
            //onSuccess
            if let user = user {
             handler(user, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteUser(handler: @escaping onCompletion) {
        
        authenticationObject.currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                handler(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            //onSuccess
            handler(true, nil)
        })
    }
    
    /// Signup User wit UserModel Object
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - user: UserModel Object
    ///   - handler: completionHandler Object
    func register(user: UserModel, handler: @escaping completionHandler) {
        
        authenticationObject.createUser(withEmail: user.email, password: user.password ) { (user, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                //onError
                if let error = error {
                    handler(nil, error)
                }
                return
            }
            //onSuccess
            if let user = user {
                handler(user, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    /// Reset Password for the associated Email Address
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - email: associated email Address
    ///   - handler: Completion Handler with Bool Optional and Error Optional
    func resetPassword(email:String, handler: @escaping onCompletion) {
        
        authenticationObject.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email) { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                handler(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            // onSuccess
            handler(true, nil)
        }
    }
    
    /// Update Password
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - newPassword: New Password as String
    ///   - handler: Competion Handler with Bool Optional for state and Error Optional
    func updatePassword(newPassword: String, handler: @escaping onCompletion) {
        
        authenticationObject.currentUser?.updatePassword(to: newPassword, completion: { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                handler(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            handler(true, nil)
        })
    }
    
    
    /// Send Verification Mail
    ///
    /// - Parameter hanlder: completionHandler with Bool Optional and Error Optional
    func sendVerificationMail(hanlder: @escaping onCompletion) {
        
        authenticationObject.useAppLanguage()
        authenticationObject.currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                hanlder(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            //onSuccess
            hanlder(true, nil)
        })
    }
    
    /// Update Email Address for Existing Account
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - newEmail: Email Address as String
    ///   - handler: completionHandler with User Optional and Error Optional
    func updateEmailAddress(newEmail: String, handler: @escaping completionHandler) {
        
        authenticationObject.currentUser?.updateEmail(to: newEmail, completion: { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                handler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            //onSuccess
            handler(self.authenticationObject.currentUser, nil)
        })
    }
    
    /// Update User Profile
    ///
    /// - Parameter handler: completion Handler with User Optional and Error Optional
    func updateProfile(handler: @escaping completionHandler) {
        
        let changeRequest = authenticationObject.currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
        
        changeRequest?.displayName = ""
        
        // Save Changes
        changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error while Changing Profile Request ...")
                handler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            // Saved Change
            handler(self.authenticationObject.currentUser, nil)
        })
    }
    
    /// Return Bool State Wheather isLoggedIn or Not
    ///
    /// - Returns: User Object
    func isLoggedIn() -> User? {
        
        return authenticationObject.currentUser
    }
    
    /// Logout Session
    ///
    /// - Returns: Execution State
    func logout() -> Bool {
        do {
            try authenticationObject.signOut()
            return true
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    
}
```