# Swift Firebase says internal error when creating a new user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create new users with Firebase but it is giving me the message "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." I have enabled the email password authentication on Firebase as well.

This is all the code that I have written as a test and it still doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pwordTxtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var continuebutton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}



@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = pwordTextField.text

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email! , password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        else {

            print("Success")
        }
    })
}




}
```

What I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579138/creating-new-user-with-firebase-in-swift

Comment: are you sure you had installed pod 'Firebase/Auth'  code is right same I  am also using and secondly print values before you send values to handler hope its. not empty and Third reconnect your outlets

Comment: have you added plist and  configured firbaseapp  on appdelegate.

Comment: yea i had plist and i configured firebaseapp on appdelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following pods in your Podfile:

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

open the auth section and enable Email/password sign-in method and save.
make sure you have added GoogleService-Info.plist file in your project.

in Appdelegate :-

```
import Firebase

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
 [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

In Viewcontroller:-

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pwordTxtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var continuebutton: UIButton!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 }



  @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

   let email = emailTextField.text
  let password = pwordTextField.text

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email! , password: password!, 
 completion: { (user, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    else {

        print("Success")
    }
})
 }




}
```

Comment: i have plist and i also enabled the auth on the google site but it wasn't/ isnt working

Comment: i just replaced the plist and it worked. Thank you so much lol

Comment: please accept my answer if your problem is resolved.