# Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((AuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void)?'

Tags: swift, xcode

```
static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        Auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let uid = user?.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)
            
            storageRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
```

Comment: Did you have a question? You have just posted a snippet of code without any explanation. I'm guessing this is Firebase but you should also mention that

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of `onSuccess` as completion, so you can just remove that and what I saw from your code is that you are trying to receive `Error` as `String` once it occurs. So, I have updated that code accordingly.

```
 static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

      Auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {         
              if let error = error {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

            let uid = user?.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)
            
            storageRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                   onError(error.localizedDescription)
                   return
                }
                   onError(nil)
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion block in Firebase Auth().createUser has a signature of ((AuthDataResult?, Error?)->Void)? i.e. it requires two parameters: result and error. You have not included any so the compiler assumes you completion block signature to be ()->()

The first line of the call should be:

```
Auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { result, error in
```

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/36586581/1852207